# Given $\angle EBD=62^\circ$ and $\angle AEB=x^\circ$, what is the value of x?

Tags: geometry

> In the diagram, $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle CDE$ are equilateral triangles. Given $\angle EBD=62^\circ$ and $\angle AEB=x^\circ$, what is the value of x?

> A) 100, B) 118, C) 120, D) 122, E) 131

> [image]

---

I've tried everything, but I just can't get $x$...can someone *please* help?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean $\angle EBD =62^\circ$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant EBD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the question is saying $\angle EBD=62^\circ$.

Since $\triangle EAC$ and $\triangle DBC$ are congruent, we have:
$$\angle CAE+\angle CBE=\angle CBD+\angle CBE=62^\circ$$

Then:
$$\angle AEB=\angle CAE+\angle CBE+\angle ACB=62^\circ+60^\circ=122^\circ$$

Comment: Thank you so much!